# RecycerView Reverse is not working

Tags: java, android

mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

```
// Add item decoration
mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(DIVIDER_SPACE));

// use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
// in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

// use a linear layout manager
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
```

Comment: Where is your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement below code. when you want to reverse the item of recyclerview just put below code to your Activity. It will work fine.

`mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);`